# Persist State Between Reloads in Nuxt v3

Tags: nuxt.js

Anyone know what the best way is to persist state between reloads in Nuxt v3?

I have my composables file states.ts:

```
export const useUser = () => useState<User | null>('user', retrieveUser)
const retrieveUser = () => {
    if (process.server) return null
    const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
    if (user) {
        try {
            const parsedUser: User = JSON.parse(user)
            if (new Date(parsedUser.expires) < new Date()) {
                localStorage.removeItem('user')
                return null
            }
            return parsedUser
        } catch (error) {
            return null
        } 
    }
    return null
}

export type User = {
    email: string
    username: string
    name: string
    zipCode: string
    profilePicture: string
    expires: Date
}
```

However, this does not do the trick. Any ideas? And how do you then go about avoiding hydration mismatches caused by using values from localStorage. It's a headache and it seems like the documentation and usage isn't too great with Nuxtjs 3 yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`useCookie`](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie) solved this issue.

```js
export const useUser = () => useCookie<User | null>('user', {
    default: () => null,
    watch: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with `useLocalStorage` from [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/core/useLocalStorage/). You can also use [custom serialisation](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/#custom-serialization) for user object.

```js
export const user = useLocalStorage<User | null>('user', () => null)
```

Beware that you cannot use `useStorage`, as it conflicts with the method of the same name from [nitro](https://nitro.unjs.io/guide/storage).